# Java: When dividing by factorials, how do I store the factorial? Its too large to be double

Tags: java, series

I am new to java, and my program is likely nowhere near as efficient as it could be, but here it is:

```
public class Compute {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(double i = 10000; i <= 100000; i += 10000)
    {
        System.out.println("The value for the series when i = " + i + " is " + e(i));
    }
}
public static double e(double input) {
    double e = 0;
    for(double i = 0; i <= input; i++)
    {
        e += 1 / factorial(input);
    }
    return e;
}
public static double factorial(double input) {
    double factorial = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= input; i++)
    {
        factorial *= i;
    }
    return factorial;
}
}
```

I believe this calculates the value e for i = 10000, 20000, ..., & 100000.
Where e = 1 + (1/1!) + (2/2!) + ... + (1/i!)
It takes about 47 seconds to do so, but I believe it works.

My issue is, for every i, the result is always 0.0
I believe this is because whenever the method factorial is called, the return value is too big to be stored which somehow causes a problem.

What can I do to store the value returned by the method Factorial?

Comment: [`100000!` has 456,574 digits](http://www.nitrxgen.net/factorialcalc.php).  Without knowing what you're _actually_ trying to accomplish it will be hard for anyone to answer your question in a meaningful way.

Comment: It is for homework, the book says nearly word for word what I said under the code about calculating e for i given the series e. I hope that makes sense, I am unsure of how to make it more understandable. :/

Comment: As Jim Garrison has pointed out, if you want to calculate e so accurately that going to 100000 terms in the series makes a difference, you'll need to store it in something other than a double.  If you really need an answer to 400000 decimal places, you should consider a BigInteger for the factorial, and a BigDecimal for both the reciprocal of the factorial, and for the partial sum.

Comment: You can stop when you have as many digits as a double can represent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you can calculate arbitrary precision results with `BigDecimal`, there is no need to calculate to `100000!` for the series expansion of *e*.  Consider that the 20th term in the series (`20/20!`) has a magnitude of about 10<sup>-19</sup>, so its contribution to the overall total is insignificant.

In other words, the contribution of any terms after the 20th would change only digits after the 19th decimal place.

Comment: +1.  I think maybe the idea of the homework is that the student will discover for himself/herself that using the series expansion for e up to 100000 terms is a waste of time, if the result is to be stored in a double.  What you've done is spoil the surprise!

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use [`java.math.BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) to store the factorial.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. I believe you should be able to calculate factorial of 10000 or even bigger numbers easily.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to understand the OP's objectives.  In calculating a series approxmation of _e_ there is no need to calculate factorials that large.

Answer (score -1):

Change this

```
e += 1 / factorial(input);
```

to

```
e += 1 / factorial(i);
```

Lots to do to speed up the code.  Think about (i+1)! vs i!, don't recalc the whole factorial every time.

Also stop calculating when the answer will change less than the required precision like Jim said.

Comment: He asked for "Where e = 1 + (1/1!) + (2/2!) + ... + (1/i!)"